# How to combine two linked list using an overloaded + operator?

Tags: c++, linked-list, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

I'm trying to overload the + operator without chaining so that way I can combine two linked list.  With my current code it doesn't seem to combine them at all.

This is my current attempt at the overloading the operator to combine the list.

```
void WORD::operator+ (const WORD & B)
{

    character *p = new character;

    while (p == 0)
    {
        Insert(p->symbol);
    }

}
```

This is the program header I was given to help write the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#ifndef WORD_H
#define WORD_H

class character
{
public:
    char symbol;
    character *next;
};

class WORD
{
public:
    bool IsEmpty() { return front == 0; };
    int Length(); //Length: Determines the length of the word A; remember A is the current object;
    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, const WORD & org); //Overload the insertion operator as a friend function with chaining to print a word A;
    void operator=(const string & s);// Overload the assignment operator as a member function to take a 
                                       //string (C-style or C++ string, just be consistent in your implementation) as an argument and 
                                       //assigns its value to A, the current object;
    WORD & operator=(const WORD & w); // Overload the assignment operator as a member function with chaining to take a word
                                    //object as an argument and assigns its value to A, the current object;
    void operator+(const WORD & B); //Overload the ‘+” operator as a member function without chaining to add word B 
                                      //(adds the set of symbols that makep B's linked list to the back of A's linked list) to the back of word A; 
                                      //remember A is the current object;
    void WORD::Insert(char key);
    WORD();//The default constructor will initialize your state variables. 
                                     //The front of the linked list is initially set to NULL or 0; this implies a non-header node 
                                     //implementation of the link list.
    WORD(const string & s); //Explicit-value constructor: This constructor will have one argument; 
                               //a C-style string or a C++ string representing the word to be created;
    WORD(const WORD & org);   // Copy Constructor: Used during a call by value, return, or initialization/declaration of a word object;
    ~WORD();                   //Destructor: The destructor will de-allocate all memory allocated for the word. Put the message 
                                 //"destructor called\n" inside the body of the destructor.
    bool IsEqual(const WORD & B);// Returns true if two word objects are equal; otherwise false; remember A is the current

private:
    character *front, *back;
};

#endif
```

Also this is "Insert" function that was used inside the overloaded operator.

```
void WORD::Insert(char key) 
{   

    character *p = new character;
    p->next = 0;
    p->symbol = key;

    if (front == 0)
    {
        front = back = p;
    }
    else
    {
        back->next = p;
        back = p;
    }

}
```

Driver to test the functionality of the overloaded operator.

```
cout << "************TEST#8*******************************" << endl;
cout << "Adding 2 words by adding us to the back of their.  Their is the current object" << endl;
WORD their("AAAA0000AAA0000AAA");
WORD us("XXXX");
their + us; 
cout<<"their followed by us is \n" <<their<< " = AAAA0000AAA0000AAAXXXX"<<endl;
cout << "*************************************************" << endl;
cout<<endl<<endl;

cout << "************TEST#9*******************************" << endl;;
cout << "Adding 2 words, their2 is empty, by adding us to the back of their.Their is the current object" << endl;;
WORD their2(""); 
their2 + us; 
cout<<"their followed by us is \n" <<their<< " = XXXX"<<endl; 
cout << "*************************************************" << endl;
cout << endl << endl;


cout << "************TEST#10*******************************" << endl;;
cout << "Adding 2 words, their3 is empty, by adding us to the back of their.Their is the current object" << endl;
WORD their3(""); 
us + their3; 
cout << "us followed by empty their3 is \n" << us << " = XXXX" << endl;
cout << "*************************************************" << endl;
cout<<endl<<endl;
```

Something worth mentioning, is that I can't really change the "Insert" function or the function header of the overloaded operator.  That being said, how would I go about combining the two linked list?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: You have `void WORD::Insert(char key);` declared within your `class WORD` definition... you don't need the `WORD::` when it is already in your `class WORD` block (and in fact it may not compile)

Comment: Also, in the `operator +` overload your `while (p==0)` won't run, since you have just assigned `p` to a new character. In fact it doesn't even look like you've used the input `B` anywhere, so I'm not quite sure how you're expecting that to work.

Comment: Presumably you need to start with `B.front`, copy that character, then get that character's `next`, copy it, and so on until you reach the `back`

Answer (score 0):

From the limited information in your question, I believe this will solve it:

```
void operator+ (const Word & B)
{
  character *p = B.front;
  while (p != 0)
  {
      Insert(p->symbol);
      p = p->next;
  }
}
```

If you post the cpp implementation file, and possibly your main, it would help in assessing the correctness of this solution.

Comment: @ProjectCBL please consider marking a correct answer. Thanks.